# Creating a Word File with formatting

Tags: ruby, formatting

I have a ruby script that creates a HTML file as the output with certain letters coloured.

e.g.

```
<p>
        <b>>aug3me.g5.t1</b> has a signal p with a cleavage site between positions 19 and 20.<br>
        <b class="SignalP">MLRSMMLMIAMGCFLNAFG</b>QSGQELE<b class="motif_site">KR</b>VI<b class="motif_site">KNAR</b>QLIYEG<b class="motif_site">KR</b>SGEGYFSKDGK<b class="motif_site">HLIFQSER</b>EEENPYYQIYILDLESGDINRVSPGQGKTTCSYFDWSSDNNVLFGSTHHDPKAKEKQQAELDF<b class="motif_site">RASGKKRR</b>YSWDYDKEMDIFSAN<b class="motif_site">RDGSNVKR</b>ITTEEGYDAEGSYSPDG<b class="motif_site">KK</b>IAFCSLRDAYN<b class="motif_site">KK</b>LSEKEIKTLEVDAAYFGEIYIMDADGSNQ<b class="motif_site">KR</b>LTNVPEPVRITHTDGFDGLPVFSPNGKNIAWTSVRTSD<b class="motif_site">KK</b>SQIFYASWDHQAALSLLKQAPAKGQDAKDPNFTGEIKSDEIKSKVAYLASDELEGRMTGSEGI<b class="motif_site">KK</b>ASDYITGQF<b class="motif_site">KK</b>IGLNSIESREEYLQEFPFVSSVEVNAAGTSFSTTN<b class="motif_site">KK</b>KPKAWVLYENFVPLPFSMNGEFEGEVVFAGYGIKTPDKSEVEYNSYANIEVKDKAVMILFDVPPHFNDDEEKELI<b class="motif_site">RYASPR</b>Y<b class="motif_site">KALVAR</b>ELGAKAVIFISE<b class="motif_site">REREFR</b>GVSKDNVPGNAGILALKVKSDLANEMLKSKETDFEKVKTQFENYNPHSENEFPLPGQTIGITTQLDKVESSDNNVIGILYADEPTDHYLMVGAHYD<b class="motif_site">HLGR</b>GEAGTLAHGEEKEEIHNGADDNASGTAAVMELAEYFVQLKNENPGSLTKNLLFALWSGEEMGLVGSAHYTKQSSKEIEGMDAYLNFDMIGMLNDNKLILQGLGSSPAWNKIVE<b class="motif_site">KK</b>NVAAGFDLTLQDDPYVPTDGMSFYQAGVPMLCFFSGIHDYYH<b class="motif_site">KPTDDIER</b>LNYEGAERIIKFSAEIIKELMKVDTLAYA<b class="motif_site">KVEMVKNR</b>AAGSKGFSVYLGTIPDYVAEVEGV<b class="motif_site">KLSGVR</b>AGGPAEKAVFRPN<b class="motif_site">KALR</b>LYGLNPLRGPH
    </p>
```

With the above sequence, certain residues (letters) are coloured in colour or another etc.

I need to make a script that makes a text file of some kind (ideally a .doc file) that has all these formattings.

Is it possible to make a script to create a word document with formatting. If so, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is the hard way and the easy way.

**Hard Way**

Use can create a Microsft Word document using WordprocessingML. I have done this in the past using an XML style sheet to transform XML output into a template, also in C# to build them from scratch.
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212812(v=office.11).aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572(v=office.12).aspx for more details on the format).

If you can create a template with the styles you need in Word. Change the extension to `.zip` and unpack. `document.xml` is the document, that can give you your base XML file to work with.

**Easy Way**

If the html file is 'stand alone', contains all the styles required, the you can cheat and just give the html file a `.doc` extention. Word will render the HTML as a word document.